# What are the specs of the DJI Mavic 2 Pro motors?

Tags: brushless-motors, dji-mavic-2

Does anyone know the specifications of the motors on the DJI Mavic 2 Pro? I'm asking about things like stator size, KV, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The most information I could find and definitely link back to the Mavic 2 is the following from the EU CE testing report:

```
1.5.1   TABLE: List of critical components
╔═════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ Object/part ║ Manufacturer/     ║ Type/model    ║ Technical data    ║
║ No.         ║ trademark         ║               ║                   ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
~             ~                   ~               ~                   ~
╠═════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ Motor of    ║ DZ DJI Technology ║ WM240-2009    ║ 14,8 V, 0,5 A     ║
║ airscrew    ║ Co Ltd            ║               ║ max. 1040 rpm/V   ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

[These](https://www.dji.com/uk/e310/spec) are the specifications from DJI’s website:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| Strator size | 23x12 mm  |
+--------------+-----------+
| KV           | 960 rpm/V |
+--------------+-----------+
| Weight       | 60g       |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I believe that's for the E310 motor, not sure that's the same one that's used on the Pro 2. I believe the Pro 2 is smaller.